# How to filter a non periodic function

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I'm new to Python programming and I wanted to know if there was a way to create a high-pass filter for a periodic function like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import lfilter, firwin, butter
from pylab import figure, plot, show
sample_rate = .0167
nsamples = 480

F_1Hz = 1.38e-4
A_1Hz = 1.0

F_15Hz = .0011
A_15Hz = .5

t = np.arange(nsamples) / sample_rate
signal = A_1Hz * np.sin(2*np.pi*F_1Hz*t) + A_15Hz*np.sin(2*np.pi*F_15Hz*t)
signal[::120] = 2
figure(1)
plot(t,signal,'b')
show()
```

I want to keep the higher frequency ( .0011 Hz) as well as the spikes of 2 at the certain spots, however the amplitudes of the .0011 Hz needs to stay at .5 and the spikes need to stay at an amplitude of 2, so normalizing isn't an option. Moreover, if I made the function have the spikes of 2 at a non-periodic intervals(say a spike at only signal[prime numbers]) could I still filter it correctly, with the correct amplitudes?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a custom high-pass filter. A simple way to make a high-pass filter is to start with a low-pass filter:

```
def lp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n):
    m = int(np.ceil( 2./tw) * 2) 
    samps = np.arange(m+1)

    shift = samps - m/2
    shift[m/2] = 1
    h = np.sin(2 * np.pi * fc * shift)/shift
    h[m/2] = 2 * np.pi * fc
    h = h * np.blackman(m+1)
    h = h / h.sum()
    s = np.zeros(n)
    s[:len(h)] = h
    return np.roll(s, -m/2)
```

Then construct a simple high-pass

```
def hp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n):
    hp = -lp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n)
    hp[0] = hp[0] + 1
    return hp
```

(The ideas behind these are found in http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm, look at the chapter on windowed-sinc filters.)

Note: these are the impulse responses of the respective filters. To apply them to your data you can either convolve the impulse with your data, or you can fft your data and the impulse response and take the inverse fft of their product. In your case, e.g.

```
hp = hp_win_sinc(0.2, 0.001, len(signal))
f_hp = np.fft.rfft(hp)
f_d = np.fft.rfft(signal)
filt_sig = np.fft.irfft( f_hp * f_d)
```

plotting this quick result gives:

[filtered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHC8h.png)

Depending on your exact application, you might be able to simply adjust the gain to recover the 2.0 and 0.5 amplitudes. Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite likely no.

The reason behind this blunt answer is that your spikes (which have a value of 2) stand on top of the signal. If you filter anything away, your signal amplitude may change at the spikes.

If you could change this:

```
signal[::120] = 2
```

into

```
signal[::120] += 2
```

then such a filter can be constructed. What do you want to filter away? Anything below .0011 Hz?